# Unified Messaging: No Speech generated by Exchange

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange

I'm testing the Unified Messaging Feature of Exchange 2010.

When I make a test call to my Voice Mailbox or the the Auto Attentant, my call gets accepted but no computer generated speech tells me what to do next. The line is just silent. No error in the eventlog.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
rAyt

Answer (score 2):

You can turn up diagnostic logging on the UM components: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb430783.aspx. That's probably the best way to start.

What device are you using to place the call? If you're using a softphone, be sure that your host firewall (if any) isn't blocking the SIP ports.